# Extract information based on a week number field

Tags: sql, date

I am using Orcle sql developer to access an MSsql database. I have week number field. and I want to extract all information that the week no is equal to the week number of today's date.

Sample Data
DutyStaff Address WeekNo Contact
John      35thd   15     670956
Peter     25 str  19     706346
Chris     40 odr  20     856294
Adam      7thstr  34     567251
Mary      6thstr  22     702457

I want to extract all rows that have the week number of today. Select * where weekno = (today's week number). The week number of today 12/05/2022 is 19 i.e current day week number

Comment: edit the question, show complete table DDL, sample data, and expected output, and your attempt

Comment: Can really Oracle SQL Developer access a SQL Server database?

Comment: Yes. Check this. [link](https://bioticssupport.natureserve.org/support/solutions/articles/216887-connecting-oracle-sql-developer-to-sql-server-database)

Comment: Sample data                                                                                                       DutyStaff Address WeekNo Contact
John 35th d  15         670956
Peter 25 str  19        706346
Chris 40 odr  20        856294
Adam 7th street  34        567251                                                                              
 I want to extarct all rows that have the week number of today. Select * where weekno = (today's week number).                                                                              
The  week number of today 12/05/2022 is 19

Answer (score 0):

select * from <table_name> as t where t.week_no =  ;
will give you all the info specific to the chosen week.

Also;
select * from <table_name> as t groupby t.week_no;
will group all info pertaining to a particular week as one.

From my understanding, this is what you were asking for, I think.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to retrive using the week no of today as the filter. e.g 'select * from <table_name> as t where t.week_no = {today's date week no}'